# How should the first "o" in "operator" be pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, speech

I've always been taught that a vowel before a double consonant following another vowel should have a short sound.  Conversely, there are many situations where a vowel preceding a single consonant and vowel gets a long sound.

Short Sounds:

```
Mississippi    - All I's except the last get short sound
Communication  - First O gets short sound
Oppose         - First O gets short sound where second O gets long
```

Long Sound:

```
Ape            - A gets long sound
Popery         - O gets long sound
Oppose         - First O gets short sound where second O gets long
```

Yet, I hear people use a short O in "operator" when using the word.  Is this the correct pronunciation?

Comment: Whether it is a short-o or long-o depends on another factor: syllabification. Operator: op-ra-tor; here, the first syllable rhymes with hop. So, you may ask how to syllabify English words? It is a complex question, which was tackled by many folks like Kahn, C-J. Bailey, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, it is. 'Operator' is pronounced ˈɒpəreɪtə (IPA), with the o- sound of 'offense' or 'orange'.

Most spellings as we use them today were standardized in the late 18th century on a fairly arbitrary basis. Most choices were based in common transliteration habits, but others followed historical convention. In this case, 'operator' had been historically spelled with a single p thanks to its root the Latin 'operari', and so the habit stuck.

*Edit: I'm aware our American cousins have some regional variations, but these accents evolved more recently.*

Comment: I guess commonality will always trump phonetics.

Comment: I have to disagree with the "offense"/"orange" comparison; for me the "o-" in "operator" is like the o in "hop", while "offense" starts with "aw" and "orange" is clearly an "or".

Comment: Southerners in the US tend towards "Awringe".

Comment: @Hellion  I've heard both very often, and I suspect they're both originally eye-readings which have achieved broad idiolectal support across many dialects&mdash;*offense* through analogy with *off*, sustained by the accent shift, and *orange* through analogy with *or*.

Comment: @hydroparadise  Some Southerners - my own East Alabama pronunciation is "Ah-reenj", with a tense second syllable, and the first syllable a dialectal realization of short "o".

Comment: @StoneyB: _West_ Alabama is that much different?

Comment: @Mitch  Fifty years ago I could have told you where a Southerner came from within fifty miles or so. Not any more; my ear's destroyed from living in Missouri, and I doubt that degree of regionalism prevails any more.

Comment: Concur: remove "orange". The first syllable is commonly pronounced like the word "or", as well as the word "are".

Comment: @Hellion - I'm talking about British English. Modern spellings were mostly finalized by Dr Johnson, who was, of course, English. US variations arose later.

Comment: I take offense from your pronunciation of "offensive".

Answer (score 7):

In America, most dialects don't distinguish between RP /ɒ/ and /a/, so *operator* is normally pronounced with [a]:

> **['apəˌɹeiɾɚ]**

Standard American is rhotic, with [ɹ] instead of [r] and final [ɚ] instead of [ə]; and the /t/ is reduced to a tap [ɾ] between a preceding stressed vowel [ei] and a following unstressed vowel [ɚ].

Comment: isn't the first vowel [ɑ]? I thought that vowel belongs to the LOT set.

Comment: There's only one low back vowel in American English; I use "a" for it because it's on my keyboard. In any event, it is not the same vowel as the one in _orange_ or _offense_, which is /ɔ/ for most Americans, at least East of the Mississippi. Except on the West Coast, where the two phonemes merge so that _Don_ with /a/ and _Dawn_ with /ɔ/ are homophonous.

Answer (score 2):

The first "o" in "operator" is pronounced with the "short o" sound found in the word "lot" (typically transcribed in the IPA as /ɑ/ in American English, and /ɒ/ in Southern British English.)

It is indeed the case that a single vowel letter tends to be pronounced as a "short vowel" before a double consonant.

But the inverse is not true: it is not uncommon for a single vowel letter to be pronounced as a "short vowel" when it does not precede a double consonant. Actually, there isn't any one rule that tells you how to pronounce a single vowel letter that comes before a single consonant letter and another vowel letter. Before certain common vowel-initial suffixes (such as *-ing, -ed, -er, -est* and *-y*) a stressed vowel tends to be "long" before a single consonant letter (note that words like *fading, closest, biker, stony* have as their bases words that end in "silent e": *fade, close, bike, stone*) but there are a number of endings that show the reverse pattern (e.g. verbs ending in *-ish,* such as *famish, perish, vanish, finish,* or adjectives ending in *-id,* such as *livid, placid, intrepid*) as well as miscellaneous words that just happen to have a short vowel before a single consonant, like *camel* (in contrast to e.g. *label*).

In *operator,* what's relevant is that there are more than two syllables after the stressed syllable. In this context, all single vowel letters except for "u" tend to be pronounced as "short" vowels. This tendency has been given various names, e.g. "Luick's law". It can be seen as related to the phenomenon of "three-syllable shortening" or "[trisyllabic laxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing)", but there are different theoretical analyses that deal with the details in different ways (e.g. "trisyllabic laxing" is often specifically used to refer to a rule about the pronunciation of derived words, and while "operator" is etymologically derived from Latin *opus, operis*, it seems very doubtful that it should be analyzed as being synchronically derived from the English word "opus").

Answer (score 0):

The phonetics rules of thumb can be useful, but there are always exceptions. This is one of them.